# How can I use drawContours OpenCV method in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I've got the following code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Convert image to grayscale image
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Convert the grayscale image to binary image
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
print(threshold)
# [[255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
#  [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
#  [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
#  ...
#  [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
#  [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
#  [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]
_, contours = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(contours)
# [[[-1 -1 -1 -1]]]
```

Why do I receive such a strange output for contours? The bottom half of my image is black and the top half is white. I expected to see `contours = [[height, 0, width, height / 2]]` where `(height, 0)` is the bottom left corner and `(width, height / 2)` is the top right corner of the black rectangle on the `image.png`.

Comment: Because what you store in variable named `contours` aren't the countours, but the hierarchy. Read the [documentatation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0).

Answer (score 0):

I should have this line of code instead (see [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0)):

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Just to add, part of the reason this is somewhat confusing is that in older versions of OpenCV, `findCountours()` returned two values. Then in later versions it returned three. Now in 4.0, it's back to two.